# Audio system Realtek ALC 899 doesn't work on 14.04.3

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, realtek

I have a notebook (**MSI GT72S 6QE Dominator Pro**), on which I installed Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS. It seems, that audio driver for **Realtek ALC 899** downloaded automatically (for example file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` exists). But it doesn't work. I tried to solve this problem and reinstall audio driver:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-alsa gnome-alsamixer
sudo apt-get purge gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio vlc-plugin-pulse pulseaudio
```

But sound didn't appeared. Furthermore, the audio settings menu has disappeared (see screenshot below):

[image]

Before deletion menu, I couldn't change output and input volume (sliders always stayed at 0), but I could freely change the main volume slider (see screenshod below - from another computer).

[image]

So, how can I install audio driver correctly?

**Additional information:** my notebook also has:

- Nahimic Audio Enhancer,
- Dynaudio subwoofer.

If you need some additional information, please write.

Comment: Have you tried following the guide on the Linux Mint community wiki?http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1236

Comment: @David, I can't find the driver for my version. I visited the [realtek site](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsCheck.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false) and if I type `ALC 899` in search field, I get `Sorry! There is no data found. Please try another keyword`. If I search the driver in `PC Audio codecs`, I don't see my version also.